# SQL Server : how to output SELECT statement in a WHILE query into one table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using the following statement :

```
DECLARE @start_date date, @end_date date;
SET @start_date = '2016-06-01';

WHILE @start_date < '2017-03-31'
BEGIN
    SET @end_date = DATEADD(day, 6, @start_date);

    SELECT @start_date AS startDate, @end_date AS endDate

    SET @start_date = DATEADD(day, 7, @start_date);
END;
```

but with the query above, it outputs a table each time it loops through the select statement, **returning output like this:**

```
+------------+------------+
| startDate  | endDate    |
+------------+------------+
| 2016-06-01 | 2016-06-07 |
+------------+------------+

+------------+------------+
| startDate  | endDate    |
+------------+------------+
| 2016-06-08 | 2016-06-14 |
+------------+------------+
```

I would like the output to be like this:

```
+------------+------------+
| startDate  | endDate    |
+------------+------------+
| 2016-06-01 | 2016-06-07 |
+------------+------------+
| 2016-06-08 | 2016-06-14 |
+------------+------------+
```

How can I combine the results into just one table as above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-- use recursive cte
; with dates as
(
    select @start_date AS startDate, DATEADD(DAY, 6, @start_date) AS endDate
    union all
    select DATEADD(DAY, 7, startDate) AS startDate, DATEADD(DAY, 7, endDate) AS endDate
    from    dates
    where   startDate < '2017-03-31'

)
select  *
from    dates
```

alternatively you may also use a number table.

If you would like to stick to your method of using WHILE - LOOP, insert the dates into a table variable or temp table, and output that after the loop